# Citation of a thesis under a CC license

Tags: bibtex

Is there any guideline to cite a work (thesis) that is licensed under a Creative Commons license?

According to the license's provision it's necessary to mention the license itself among other details.

How is this done with BibTex?

Edit: In particular I am interested how the BibTeX entry should look like and how the necessary CC attribution information should be mentioned in the bibliography of my thesis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! This seems very borderline for us: in the first instance I'd consider raising the concept on the Academia cite. A citation is a pointer to a source, so the license of that source is irrelevant. Perhaps you are reusing an element from it (such as a graphic)?

Comment: There's nothing special to do for *citing* some work; “quoting” it is a different thing. What kind of CC license is the work released with?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about an input format when you have no idea what the output should be.

Comment: Better try your chances on http://academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: You still don't mention what CC license you're talking about. However, the licenses say that if you *share* the document you need to indicate the license. Citing is not sharing: it's just telling what document you have consulted and giving information about it, which might contain a URI pointing to the document. There's no mention of “citation” in the licenses. Even quoting small parts of the document can't be disallowed under many jurisdictions, provided attribution is clearly shown and the quotation is short.